# Missing Method ShowViewModel when trying to navigate in Android

Tags: mvvmcross

In my core PCL library I'm trying to navigate to a new activity with ShowViewModel(); My ViewModel inherits from MvxViewModel. When I run this command I get:

```
Missing method Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject::ShowViewModel<[1]>(IMvxBundle,IMvxBundle,MvxRequestedBy) in assembly Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll, referenced in assembly ...
```

ADB gives shows a similar message:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel'
```

I am running MvvmCross 3.1.1. I used Visual Studio to install the core packages and Xamarin Studio to install the Android packages since I only have the indie version of Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of mismatch in your manual multi-environment install - try comparing your project against one that works.

Answer (score 2):

I think Stuart's comment is correct. I removed all of the NuGet packages, then re-added them all in Xamarin Studio and it works great.

My best guess is that this may have something to do with the NuGet support in Xamarin Studio vs Visual Studio. I know that the NuGet plugin I am using doesn't support the newest NuGet.